# Page not loading at the top

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a single page website. When I visit the domain of the site, it starts me off half way down the page. I'm not sure what's causing this. Has anyone experienced this before? I can provide the link to the site if necessary.

My index.php page....

```
<?php
    require "requires/top.php";
    require "requires/nav.php";
    require "main/landed.php";
    require "main/about.php";
    require "main/galleries.php";
    require "main/contact.php";
    require "requires/footer.php";
?>


<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/wow.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> new WOW().init(); </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/instafeed.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/magic.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/contest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/feed.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/feed2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/gal-switch.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.form/4.2.1/jquery.form.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes, please post the link.

Comment: http://jackloudphoto.com/

Comment: Your page is loading perfectly fine. The problem is that it's automaticly scrolling down underneath your image slider. It's most likely caused by a setting or somewhere in the JS file related to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your page scrolls down because it centers the "First Name" input in the contact section because it has the `autofocus` attribute.

```
<div id="first-name-group" class="form-group">
    <input type="text" name="txtFirstName" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" id="firstName" autofocus>
</div>
```

Just remove the `autofocus` attribute.

If you want to learn more I recommend to read the [MDN Web Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/autofocus).

Answer (score 1):

When someone visits your website, the menu at the top has **Photography** selected by default, which has the anchor tag's href set to `#gallery` *(line 24 in source code)*. The page loads to the div element that has the exact `id` attribute *(line 110 in source code)* of `gallery`.

There is code that is executing an animation based on which menu tag is set as the default by whatever CMS you are using. I would change the default page to be set to **Home**, which would then ensure that the homepage always loads at the top.